# How to send a SignalR message to a user?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

How does the client authorize to send a message to the user?

Sending from the controller

```
hubContext.Clients.User(User.Identity.Name).SendAsync();
```

At the moment the message is not sent. Do I need to add something in OnConnection ()? Or does SignalR have a ready-made mapping mechanism for ConnectionId and User.Identity.Name?

That's how I implemented it at the moment, but it seems to me not quite right. The question is how to make the same standard tools?

```
    public static class HubConnections
{
    public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> Users = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public static List<string> GetUserId(string name)
    {
        return Users[name];
    }
}

public class GameHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {


        if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated 
            && HubConnections.Users.ContainsKey(Context.User.Identity.Name) 
            && !HubConnections.Users[Context.User.Identity.Name].Contains(Context.ConnectionId))
                HubConnections.Users[Context.User.Identity.Name].Add(Context.ConnectionId);
        else 
            HubConnections.Users.Add(Context.User.Identity.Name, new List<string> { Context.ConnectionId });

        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) HubConnections.Users.Remove(Context.User.Identity.Name);

        return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

As I said above, I tried just like this, and it does not work

```
hubContext.Clients.User(User.Identity.Name).SendAsync();
```

Comment: Please check the documentation, it is very well explained and documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Rereading more than once. I did not find the necessary information

Comment: The question is very broad, we need more code, please show what you have tried, the classes that probably have the problem with more details.

Comment: updated, check please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was chasing the same issue and got the solution from https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2498

One needs to set the NameIdentifier claim. That is the one checked by SignalR instead of the Name claim which I assumed. I set the NameIdentifier claim and I got my non-hub class to send a notification to a specific user.

Answer (score 1):

The claim that signalR is using to identify the user can be changed. It is important to ensure that this claim has unique values.

Documentation says to setup a custom UserIdProvider like this:

```
public class NameUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
    {
        return connection.User?.Identity?.Name;
    }
}
```

Add then add it to services:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... other services ...

    services.AddSignalR();
    services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();
}
```

The snippets are taken from official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-claims-to-customize-identity-handling

Answer (score 0):

There's a client-side component. You must reference the SignalR JS file, create a connection and then subscribe to a particular message from the server. Only then will sending that message actually do something.

```
<script src="~/lib/signalr/signalr.js"></script>
<script>
    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
       .withUrl("/gameHub")
       .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
       .build();

    connection.on("Foo", (data) => {
        // do something
    });

    connection.start().catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
</script>
```

The above will then cause the client to run the function defined for `"Foo"` above whenever the server sends a `"Foo"` message like:

```
hubContext.Clients.User(User.Identity.Name).SendAsync("Foo", data);
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is already done.
The problem is with User.
If I do for example Clients.All, then everything works and the event is triggered, but
 Client.User (User.Identity.Name) is ignored

Comment: If you user actually authenticated?

Comment: Yes, it is authorized. And User.Identity.Name stores its Username

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `Users` as a store for the connection id. So, for each username, you can send the message to each of the client connections you have stored for that user. Something like this:

```
public void SendMessage(string username, object data)
{
    var connections = HubConnections.Users[Context.User.Identity.Name];

    foreach(var id in connections)
    {
        Clients.client(id).SendAsync("Foo", data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to use Clients.User (username) and this is why it does not work.
I have already implemented the method described by you, but it’s somehow wrong, mine